# Multiple Rows in to One Row

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a result set in oracle as below: let the table name t1

```
Name    | phase|   a_plan  | a_actual | b_plan   | b_actual  |  c_plan  | c_actual
===================================================================================
RKM     | m5-m6|   1/1/2014|1/6/2014  | 2/2/2014 |           |  3/3/2014|
RKM     | m5-m6|   1/1/2014|          | 2/2/2014 | 4/2/2014  |  3/3/2014|
RKM     | m5-m6|   1/1/2014|          | 2/2/2014 |           |  3/3/2014| 5/3/2014
```

Whereas I need the result set as below in a single row:(a-Plan, b_plan,c_plan will be same across all 3 rows only actual column chnages per row)

```
Name    | phase|   a_plan  | a_actual | b_plan   | b_actual  |  c_plan  | c_actual
===================================================================================
RKM     | m5-m6|   1/1/2014|1/6/2014  | 2/2/2014 | 4/2/2014  |  3/3/2014| 5/3/2014
```

Help in framing the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT NAME, 
       phase, 
       a_plan, 
       Max(a_actual), 
       b_plan, 
       Max(b_actual), 
       c_plan, 
       Max(c_actual) 
FROM   table 
GROUP  BY NAME, 
          phase, 
          a_plan, 
          b_plan, 
          c_plan
/
```

Comment: Thanks Bro... Lalit Kumar B ... it was so simple.. just i panicked and thought of asking